# Множественная выборка yii2

Tags: mysql, yii2, yii, php, sql

Есть форма, для добавления новой книги:

```
name: Книга1
year: 1954
lang:  ?
```

Книга может быть и на 1, и на 30 языках, мне нужно выбрать только необходимые.  
Список языков реализован через **ListBox** (обычный html компонент).   
Есть таблица, где перечисляются книга и на каких языках она написана:

**book_lang:**

```
id_book  |  lang
   1         ru
   1         en
   1         fr
```

Мой вариант, как добавить в таблицу book_lang выбранные языки:

```
$book->save();
foreach($_POST as $row)
{
   $book_lang->id = $book->id;
   $book_lang->lang = $row['lang'];
   $book_lang->save();
}
```

Как вам мой вариант? Может, в Yii2 есть какой-то способ сделать по-другому и лучше, подскажите, если не сложно. Спасибо.

Comment: В зависимости от того, какие манипуляции нужно сделать с данными, их можно по разному хранить в БД. Если эти данные просто указывают на каких языках есть, то можно в текстовом поле хранить json объект. Создаете массив из lang. и потом $langStr = json_encode(array); и храните строку в одном поле, потом при выводе $langArray = json_decode($langStr, true) .

Comment: Здесь нужно именно в БД, мой вариант подходит для yii2?